# Other assumption on monotone convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

The MCT (monotone convergence theorem) says that if $(f_n)$ is an increasing sequence of positive measurable functions which converges a.e. to a function $f$ on $\Omega$, then $f$ is measurable and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_\Omega f_n(x)=\int_\Omega \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) $$

A corollary states that if $(f_n)$ is an increasing sequence of functions in $L^1$ which converges a.e. to a function $f$ on $\Omega$, then $f$ is measurable and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_\Omega f_n(x)=\int_\Omega \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) $$

To prove this corollary, I used $g_n=f_n-f_1 \geq 0$, $f_1 \in L^1 \implies \int f_1 < \infty $ and the theorem gives $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_\Omega g_n(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_\Omega f_n-f_1=\int_\Omega \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n= \int_\Omega \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n-f_1=\int_\Omega f-f_1$$

I can only use linearity of the integral for positive and meas. functions so I struggle to finish this proof since $f_n$ can be non-negative. Also I am feeling that I am not using enough the fact that all $f_n$s are in $L^1$. Can someone help ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving slight extension of the Monotone Convergence Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3633390/proving-slight-extension-of-the-monotone-convergence-theorem)

Comment: @AnneBauval It gives me ideas but no it does not answer my question because s/he splits the sum